# subprocess returns different output than shell

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, pipe, github-cli

Short context: Github's `gh` client adds ANSI colors to its JSON output, which is nice but makes post process hard. So if you pipe the output, gh makes a slightly different and regularly encoded output, for example:

```
gh api organizations | cat
```

prints something like

```
[{"login":"errfree","id":44,"node_id":"MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjQ0","url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/events","hooks_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/hooks","issues_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/issues","members_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/members{/member}","public_members_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/public_members{/member}","avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/44?v=4","description":null},
```

However, if I do the same with subprocess via

```
p = subprocess.run('gh api organizations | cat', shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout.decode())
```

the result is completely different:

[image]

Why? And: Is there an option to force the command (in my case `gh`) to behave like it would be piped?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I try what you did, I don't get the indentation or colors.